# AWS EC2 free tier instance is automatically stopping frequently

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, apache, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-18.04

I am using ubuntu 18.04 on AWS EC2 instace free tier, running websites on apache server, NodeJS with PostgreSQL database. All deployments are done perfectly and webapps works fine without any exception or error details.

However I am facing an annoying issue: this instance is stopping frequently without any exception or error logs. After rebooting instance everything starts working fine but after some time it automatically stops either in few hrs. on same day when rebooted instance or in 1-2 days after that.

I created another free tier instance with seperate account and that is also giving same issue. I am not finding any logs or troubleshoot option to get rid of this problem.

I would like to know how it can be troubleshooted or where can i find logs of any errors or exception for this isntance?

Suggestion given by AWS in "Instance Status Checl" as attached below are not practicle solution to apply evertime.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: The problem is nothing to do with free tier. Your application, or its configuration, is likely the cause of the problem. Apache logs may be in /var/log/apache2/. Your application logs are wherever your application wrote them (assuming it actually wrote logs). Other, Ubuntu logs are likely in /var/log/.

Comment: @jarmod thanks for reply, I will check it out and see if its showing any errors.

Answer (score 0):

Something with your VM itself is causing its health checks to fail.

Have a look at syslogs, and your application logs. Also take a look at CloudWatch metrics to see if any metrics have dramatic change close to time.

You can also add a CloudWatch alarm with a [recovery action](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-recover.html)  to automatically reboot if there’s an issue with your VM.

Comment: thanks for reply, I will check it out and see if its showing any errors.